# URL Paths in HTML and CSS files

Tags: javascript, html, css

Maybe title of this question is a little bit confusing to you but i will explain in detail.

Imagine you are developing a site (PHP SCRIPT) which has images, js files and background image urls in css.
You need to make it work if user who purchased it put it in subfolder like:

```
www.example.com/subfolder
```

or when he put it in `www.example.com`

If I use path for background image in my CSS like this:

```
background: url(/assets/img/thumbs-up.png) no-repeat;
```

This will work if user place script in `www.example.com` but if he places in `www.example.com/subfolder`, browser will be requesting `www.example.com/assets/img/thumbs-up.png` instead of `www.example.com/subfolder/assets/img/thumbs-up.png`

This is usually solved using this

```
background: url(assets/img/thumbs-up.png) no-repeat;
```

But no, in my case the browser is requesting this url instead

```
http://www.example.com/subfolder/assets/css/assets/img/thumbs-up.png
```

This part, `assets/css` is where CSS file is located.

I fixed this by using

```
background: url(../../assets/img/thumbs-up.png) no-repeat;
```

This works in root `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/subfolder`
But is it a good practice?

For JS files, I include script like this

```
<script src="assets/js/single_load.js"></script>
```

This works because file having this code is located in root of the script.
(`http://www.example.com/index.php` or `http://www.example.com/subfolder/index.php` is calling it, if a file in subfolder called JS i think I would have to add `../` many times depending in how many subfolders file is located)

Any thoughts, guides on this?

Comment: Before placing any answers if question is unclear please let me know in the comments what I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use one path for your CSS file in all PHP scripts.

The path to image will be located from your **CSS** path, not PHP

For example:

```
- index.php
- subfolder
    --index.php
-assets
    --css
        ---style.css
    --img
```

style.css

```
background: url(../assets/img/thumbs-up.png) no-repeat;
```

config.php

```
<?php
$root_path = "www.example.com";
//OR $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; if you have one index.php
```

root index.php

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<link href="<?php echo $root_path;?>/assets/css/style.css">
```

subfolder/index.php

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<link href="<?php echo $root_path;?>/assets/css/style.css">
```